# Sometime I get null in token when I am using FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I am using below method to get token but sometimes (not every time) it returns **null**.

```
String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating the instance ID token may take some time. This means that while the initial token is being generated,`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` will return `null` that is expected behavior.

If you want to capture when the initial token gets generated, as well as when the token is refreshed, have a look at [monitoring the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation). This means you'll need to implement a service, since the token may be refreshes while your app isn't active.